Is there a mantra for pure happiness?
I've read in some books that to be happy is the highest form of worship.
Also all material possessions etc. are all for happiness.
There must be a direct way to attain a long-lasting blissfull state of happiness.
Is there such a way in Hinduism as in the form of a mantra or meditation?

simply chant OM

Yes, intoning Nityaananda mentally or out loud would certainly bring pure ecstatic happiness. Will come faster if done with some faith. OM also grants all happiness in creation.

According to scriptures you cannot remain happy if your consciousness is on material platform. So to elevate yourself to spiritual platform you have to connect to God. In vedic scriptures this process is called Yoga (To connect back). There are three main types of Yoga, Hatha Yoga (Control Breath and Focus within), Gyan Yoga (Detail analysis and study of vedic scriptures) and Bhakti Yoga (Serving God). According to Bhagavat Gita, Arjuna asks for these types of Yoga and is explained by Lord Shri Krishna. But Arjuna gets overwhelmed by the difficulty of different Yogas. So asks Lord Shri Krishna for easy method. In which Lord Shri Krishna suggests, serving Him by serving the Guru who is His representative, offering Him Food, glorifying Him.
One of the easiest method I have learnt myself is glorifying Him. For that you can read Ramayan, Mahabharat and Bhagvatam (Bhagvat Puran).
But acharyas have given even more easy way, that is chant His names. There is Lord Vishnu's 1000 names. One of the famous method that is known today is the Hare Krishna Mantra.
Sorry I made it long but needed to explain. So the Mantra for true happiness is the one which will connect you to Lord Shri Krishna.
But I would suggest that you find people who practice these types of yoga and try to feel their happiness, its an energy which will transfer to you.

@thanks for your answer. I am aware of Vishnu Sahasranamam and listened to it 10 days in a row a couple of years back. On the last day I was so joyful, but the feeling subsided after some time. I feel somehow that if one does something like a routine one tends to lose interest and doesn't do the bhakti with full devotion any more. So is the answer simply to put in the effort every single day? I've read some texts by Rupert Spira, that it takes absolutely no effort to abide as pure awareness, but it takes practice.
